# Average over a timeframe with missing data

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, average

Assuming a table such as:

```
UID     Name        Datetime                Users
4       Room 4      2012-08-03 14:00:00     3
2       Room 2      2012-08-03 14:00:00     3
3       Room 3      2012-08-03 14:00:00     1
1       Room 1      2012-08-03 14:00:00     2

3       Room 3      2012-08-03 14:15:00     1
2       Room 2      2012-08-03 14:15:00     4
1       Room 1      2012-08-03 14:15:00     3

1       Room 1      2012-08-03 14:30:00     6

1       Room 1      2012-08-03 14:45:00     3
2       Room 2      2012-08-03 14:45:00     7
3       Room 3      2012-08-03 14:45:00     8
4       Room 4      2012-08-03 14:45:00     4
```

I wanted to get the average user count of each room (1,2,3,4) from the time 2PM to 3PM. The problem is that sometimes the room may not "check in" at the 15 minute interval time, so the assumption has to be made that the previous last known user count is still valid.

For example the check-in's for `2012-08-03 14:15:00` room 4 never checked in, so it must be assumed that room 4 had 3 users at `2012-08-03 14:15:00` because that is what it had at `2012-08-03 14:00:00`

This follows on through so that the average user count I am looking for is as follows:

Room 1: (2 + 3 + 6 + 3) / 4 = 3.5
Room 2: (3 + 4 + `4` + 7) / 4 = 4.5
Room 3: (1 + 1 + `1` + 8) / 4 = 2.75
Room 4: (3 + `3` + `3` + 4) / 4 = 3.25

where `#` is the assumed number based on the previous known check-in.

I am wondering if it's possible to so this with SQL alone? if not I am curious of a ingenious PHP solution that isn't just bruteforce math, as such as my quick inaccurate pseudo code:

```php
foreach ($rooms_id_array as $room_id) {
    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE (`UID` == $room_id && `Datetime` >= 2012-08-03 14:00:00 && `Datetime` <= 2012-08-03 15:00:00)";
    $result = query($SQL);
    if ( count($result) < 4 ) {
        // go through each date and find what is missing, and then go to previous date and use that instead
    } else {
        foreach ($result)
            $sum += $result;
        $avg = $sum / 4;
    }

}
```

Comment: SQL has SUM() , CNT() and AVG() aggregate functions.

Comment: The calculation of average user count is little confusing. If you have  check in an check out time, then very easily we can find out average user count. I doubt whether it is correct if we just use check in time

Comment: I don't think it are check-in/check-out times, but just observations. The missing observations have to be filled in by the most recent previous value for the same room. Plus he needs a calendar table (or generate_series function) to supply the "ticks".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this solution:

```sql
SELECT   b.Name, 
         AVG(b.Users) avg_users
FROM     (
         SELECT     a.UID, 
                    MAX(c.Datetime) last_date
         FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM tbl) a
         CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT '14:00:00' intrvl UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:15:00'        UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:30:00'        UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:45:00'
                    ) b
         JOIN       tbl c ON a.UID           = c.UID
                         AND TIME(b.intrvl) >= TIME(c.Datetime)
         GROUP BY   a.UID,
                    b.intrvl
         ) a
JOIN     tbl b ON a.UID       = b.UID
              AND a.last_date = b.Datetime
GROUP BY b.UID,
         b.Name
```

---

## Query Breakdown:

---

### Step 1:

The first thing we need to do is associate each room with each time-interval. For example, in your example data, `Room 4` does not have an association with intervals `14:15:00` and `14:30:00`, but we still need to somehow represent those associations.

We accomplish this by creating a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join) of each distinct room with the relevant time-intervals:

```sql
SELECT     a.UID, 
           b.intrvl
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM tbl) a
CROSS JOIN (
           SELECT '14:00:00' intrvl UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:15:00'        UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:30:00'        UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:45:00'
           ) b
ORDER BY   b.intrvl, a.UID DESC --Ordering for display purposes
```

*Renders:*

```
UID | intrvl
--------------
4   | 14:00:00
3   | 14:00:00
2   | 14:00:00
1   | 14:00:00
4   | 14:15:00
3   | 14:15:00
2   | 14:15:00
1   | 14:15:00
4   | 14:30:00
3   | 14:30:00
2   | 14:30:00
1   | 14:30:00
4   | 14:45:00
3   | 14:45:00
2   | 14:45:00
1   | 14:45:00
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/002e3/34)

---

### Step 2:

Then once we have those associations, we join the result back onto the main table (`tbl`) on the condition that the main table's time part of its `Datetime` field is less than the Cartesian-joined time for each `UID`. What this will do is for each `UID` -> `intrvl` association, it will show all entries that have occurred on or before the `intrvl` time.

So for example, since `Room 3` doesn't have an entry for the `14:30:00` intrvl, only two entries will join with that intrvl: the ones on `14:15:00` and `14:00:00` since they both occurred either on or before the intrvl time.

You can now see where we are going with this. The result of this step will give us access to the most recent entry for each intrvl.

```sql
SELECT     a.UID, 
           b.intrvl,
           c.*
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM tbl) a
CROSS JOIN (
           SELECT '14:00:00' intrvl UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:15:00'        UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:30:00'        UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:45:00'
           ) b
JOIN       tbl c ON a.UID           = c.UID
                AND TIME(b.intrvl) >= TIME(c.Datetime)
ORDER BY   b.intrvl, a.UID DESC, c.Datetime --Ordering for display purposes
```

*Renders (excluding the `Name` column):*

```
UID |  intrvl    |  Datetime             |  Users
---------------- --------------------------------
4   |  14:00:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  3   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:00:00
3   |  14:00:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  1   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:00:00
2   |  14:00:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  3   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:00:00
1   |  14:00:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  2   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:00:00
4   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  3   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:15:00
3   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  1
3   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  1   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:15:00
2   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  3
2   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  4   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:15:00
1   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  2
1   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  3   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:15:00
4   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  3   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:30:00
3   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  1   
3   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  1   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:30:00
2   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  3
2   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  4   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:30:00
1   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  2
1   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  3
1   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:30:00  |  6   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:30:00
4   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  3
4   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:45:00  |  4   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:45:00
3   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  1
3   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  1
3   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:45:00  |  8   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:45:00
2   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  3
2   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  4
2   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:45:00  |  7   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:45:00
1   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00  |  2
1   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00  |  3
1   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:30:00  |  6
1   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:45:00  |  3   <-- Most recent entry up until 14:45:00
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/002e3/28)

---

### Step 3:

Our next step is to take the result-set above and pull only the most recent joined `Datetime` for each intrvl. We can accomplish this by using `GROUP BY` in conjunction with the `MAX()` aggregate function.

Unfortunately, we can't also correctly pull the value of `Users` along with each of the selected `Datetime`s due to how `GROUP BY` behaves.

```sql
SELECT     a.UID, 
           b.intrvl,
           MAX(c.Datetime) last_date
FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM tbl) a
CROSS JOIN (
           SELECT '14:00:00' intrvl UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:15:00'        UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:30:00'        UNION ALL
           SELECT '14:45:00'
           ) b
JOIN       tbl c ON a.UID           = c.UID
                AND TIME(b.intrvl) >= TIME(c.Datetime)
GROUP BY   a.UID,
           b.intrvl
ORDER BY   b.intrvl, a.UID DESC --Again, for display purposes
```

*Renders:*

```
UID |  intrvl    |  last_date
---------------------------------------
4   |  14:00:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00
3   |  14:00:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00
2   |  14:00:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00
1   |  14:00:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00
4   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00
3   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00
2   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00
1   |  14:15:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00
4   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:00:00
3   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00
2   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:15:00
1   |  14:30:00  |  2012-08-03 14:30:00
4   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:45:00
3   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:45:00
2   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:45:00
1   |  14:45:00  |  2012-08-03 14:45:00
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/002e3/30)

---

### Step 4

Now we have to grab the value of `Users` for each `last_date` so we can take the average of those values. We do this by wrapping our query in the last step as a subselect inside the `FROM` clause and joining once again back onto the main table on the condition that for each matching `UID` -> `last_date` association, grab the value of `Users`.

```sql
SELECT   a.UID,
         a.last_date,
         b.Users
FROM     (
         SELECT     a.UID, 
                    MAX(c.Datetime) last_date
         FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM tbl) a
         CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT '14:00:00' intrvl UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:15:00'        UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:30:00'        UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:45:00'
                    ) b
         JOIN       tbl c ON a.UID           = c.UID
                         AND TIME(b.intrvl) >= TIME(c.Datetime)
         GROUP BY   a.UID,
                    b.intrvl
         ) a
JOIN     tbl b ON a.UID       = b.UID
              AND a.last_date = b.Datetime
ORDER BY a.UID DESC --Display purposes again
```

*Renders:*

```
UID | last_date           | Users
---------------------------------
4   | 2012-08-03 14:00:00 | 3
4   | 2012-08-03 14:00:00 | 3
4   | 2012-08-03 14:00:00 | 3
4   | 2012-08-03 14:45:00 | 4
3   | 2012-08-03 14:00:00 | 1
3   | 2012-08-03 14:15:00 | 1
3   | 2012-08-03 14:15:00 | 1
3   | 2012-08-03 14:45:00 | 8
2   | 2012-08-03 14:00:00 | 3
2   | 2012-08-03 14:15:00 | 4
2   | 2012-08-03 14:15:00 | 4
2   | 2012-08-03 14:45:00 | 7
1   | 2012-08-03 14:00:00 | 2
1   | 2012-08-03 14:15:00 | 3
1   | 2012-08-03 14:30:00 | 6
1   | 2012-08-03 14:45:00 | 3
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/002e3/32)

---

### Step 5

Now it's just a simple matter of grouping on each room and averaging the `Users` column:

```sql
SELECT   b.Name, 
         AVG(b.Users) avg_users
FROM     (
         SELECT     a.UID, 
                    MAX(c.Datetime) last_date
         FROM       (SELECT DISTINCT UID FROM tbl) a
         CROSS JOIN (
                    SELECT '14:00:00' intrvl UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:15:00'        UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:30:00'        UNION ALL
                    SELECT '14:45:00'
                    ) b
         JOIN       tbl c ON a.UID           = c.UID
                         AND TIME(b.intrvl) >= TIME(c.Datetime)
         GROUP BY   a.UID,
                    b.intrvl
         ) a
JOIN     tbl b ON a.UID       = b.UID
              AND a.last_date = b.Datetime
GROUP BY b.UID,
         b.Name
```

*Renders:*

```
Name   | avg_users
------------------
Room 1 | 3.5
Room 2 | 4.5
Room 3 | 2.75
Room 4 | 3.25
```

[*SQLFiddle Demo of Final Result*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/002e3/33)

Comment: Do note that Step 2 is a half Cartesian product.  This means that `TIME(b.intrvl) >= TIME(c.Datetime)` *can* match on an unnecessarily large number of records; For example, there are 56 fifteen minute intervals prior to `14:00`.  This could possibly be *moderated* (but not totally avoided) by using something like `AND TIME(c.Datetime) >= '14:00'`.  Also, by using the `TIME()` function, this will match on records from previous dates, thus something like `AND c.Datetime >= '2012-08-03' AND c.DateTime < '2012-08-04'`.  Finally, using `TIME()` also prevents the use of indexes in that join.

Answer (score 6):

Your difficulty *(most costly step)* will be to fill in the blanks.  If it is not possible to "fill in the blanks" in your source data, you probably want to have a template to join on, then use correlated-sub-queries to find the data associated with that template.

This is often best with real tables, but here is an example with hard-coded in-line-views instead...

```sql
SELECT
  `room`.`uid`           `uid` ,
  AVG(`data`.`users`)    `average_users`
FROM
  (SELECT 1 `UID`  UNION ALL
   SELECT 2 `UID`  UNION ALL
   SELECT 3 `UID`  UNION ALL
   SELECT 4 `UID`)                                     `room`
CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT '2012-08-03 14:00:00' `datetime`  UNION ALL
   SELECT '2012-08-03 14:15:00' `datetime`  UNION ALL
   SELECT '2012-08-03 14:30:00' `datetime`  UNION ALL
   SELECT '2012-08-03 14:45:00' `datetime`)            `checkin`
LEFT JOIN
  data
    ON  `data`.`uid`      = `room`.`uid`
    AND `data`.`datetime` = (SELECT MAX(`datetime`)
                               FROM `data`
                              WHERE `uid`       = `room`.`uid`
                                AND `datetime` <= `checkin`.`datetime`)
GROUP BY
  `room`.`uid`
```

*- The `CROSS JOIN` creates the template to ensure that you always have a record for every checkin slot for every room.*

*- The `correlated sub-query` searches back through time to find the most recent checkin for that room at that time.*

Answer (score 2):

I just played around a bit with [MySQL variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html) and came up with the following idea:

Just calculate the (discrete) integral of users over time, and then divide by the total time.

```
SET @avgSum := @lastValue := @lastTime := @firstTime := 0;
SELECT
  *,
  @firstTime := IF(@firstTime = 0, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DateTime`), @firstTime),
  @avgSum := @avgSum + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DateTime`) - @lastTime) * @lastValue,
  @lastValue,
  @lastTime,
  @lastValue := `Users`,
  @lastTime := UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DateTime`),
  @avgSum / (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DateTime`) - @firstTime) AS `average`
FROM
  `table`
WHERE
  `UID` = 1 AND
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DateTime`) >= … AND
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DateTime`) < …
ORDER BY
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`DateTime`) ASC;
```

`@firstTime` is the timestamp of the first user record, `@avgSum` the sum of users over time (the integral). `@lastValue` and `@lastTime` are value and time of the previous record. The column `average` is the total sum of users divides by the whole interval (don't mind the `NULL` due to division by zero for the first record).

Two restrictions are still present: The first and the last record for the given interval must be present. Without, the average "ends" at the last available record.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this does a pretty good job of accommodating all time frames, even if the check-in intervals are not even.  Also, I think you have an error in your example; in your weighted averages, room 2 has a "4" instead of "7" for the last value.

The setup:

```
if object_id(N'avgTbl', N'U') is not null
drop table avgTbl;

create table avgTbl (
    UserId int not null,
    RoomName nvarchar(10) not null,
    CheckInTime datetime not null,
    UserCount int not null,

    constraint pk_avgTbl primary key (UserId, RoomName, CheckInTime)
);

insert into avgTbl (UserId, RoomName, CheckInTime, UserCount) values
(4, 'Room 4', '2012-08-03 14:00:00', 3),
(2, 'Room 2', '2012-08-03 14:00:00', 3),
(3, 'Room 3', '2012-08-03 14:00:00', 1),
(1, 'Room 1', '2012-08-03 14:00:00', 2),

(3, 'Room 3', '2012-08-03 14:15:00', 1),
(2, 'Room 2', '2012-08-03 14:15:00', 4),
(1, 'Room 1', '2012-08-03 14:15:00', 3),

(1, 'Room 1', '2012-08-03 14:30:00', 6),

(1, 'Room 1', '2012-08-03 14:45:00', 3),
(2, 'Room 2', '2012-08-03 14:45:00', 7),
(3, 'Room 3', '2012-08-03 14:45:00', 8),
(4, 'Room 4', '2012-08-03 14:45:00', 4);
```

The query:

```
/* 
* You just need to enter the start and end times below.  
* They can be any intervals, as long as the start time is 
* before the end time.
*/
declare 
    @startTime datetime = '2012-08-03 14:00:00',
    @endTime datetime = '2012-08-03 15:00:00';

declare     
    @totalTime numeric(18,1) = datediff(MINUTE, @startTime, @endTime);

    /*
    * This orders the observations, and assigns a sequential number so we can 
    *join on it later.
    */
with diffs as (
    select 
        row_number() over (order by RoomName, CheckInTime) as RowNum,
        CheckInTime,
        UserCount,
        RoomName
    from avgTbl
),
/*
* Get the time periods, 
* calc the number of minutes, 
* divide by the total minutes in the period, 
* multiply by the UserCount to get the weighted value, 
* sum the weighted values to get the weighted avg.
*/
mins as (
    select 
        cur.RoomName,
        /*
        * If we do not have an observation for a given room, use "0" instead
        * of "null", so it does not affect calculations later.
        */
        case 
            when prv.UserCount is null then 0
            else prv.UserCount
            end as UserCount, 
        /* The current observation time. */            
        cur.CheckInTime as CurrentT,
        /* The prior observation time. */
        prv.CheckInTime as PrevT,
        /*
        * The difference in minutes between the current, and previous qbservation
        * times.  If it is the first observation, then use the @startTime as the
        * previous observation time.  If the current time is null, then use the
        * end time.
        */
        datediff(MINUTE, 
            case 
                when prv.CheckInTime is null then @startTime 
                else prv.CheckInTime 
                end, 
            case 
                when cur.CheckInTime is null then @endTime 
                else cur.CheckInTime 
                end) as Mins 
    from diffs as cur
        /*
        * Join the observations based on the row numbers.  This gets the current,
        * and previous observations together in the same record, so we can 
        * perform our calculations.
        */
        left outer join diffs as prv on cur.RowNum = prv.RowNum + 1
            and cur.RoomName = prv.RoomName
    union
    /*
    * Add the end date as a period end, assume that the user count is the same 
    * as the last observation.
    */
    select 
        d.RoomName, 
        d.UserCount, 
        @endTime,
        d.CheckInTime, -- The last recorded observation time.
        datediff(MINUTE, d.CheckInTime, @endTime) as Mins
    from diffs as d 
    where d.RowNum in (
        select MAX(d2.RowNum)
        from diffs as d2
        where d2.RoomName = d.RoomName
        )
    group by d.RoomName, d.CheckInTime, d.UserCount
)
/* Now we just need to get our weighted average calculations. */
select 
    m.RoomName, 
    count(1) - 1 as NumOfObservations,
    /*
    * m.Min = minutes during which "UserCount" is the active number.
    * @totalTime = total minutes between start and end.
    * m.Min / @totalTime = the % of the total time.
    * (m.Min / @totalTime) * UserCount = The weighted value.
    * sum(..above..) = The total weighted average across the observations.
    */
    sum((m.Mins/@totalTime) * m.UserCount) as WgtAvg
from mins as m
group by m.RoomName
order by m.RoomName;
```